# Can I switch an template's parameter type during calling it at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, typename

Firstly, I have a class Manager which could manage diferents primitive data types. For that reason, the Manager has template methods. To call them I have multiple methods with a switch case to select with what type the template method will be called.

I have the next code on C++:

```
enum MyCallType
{
   MCT_DOUBLE,
   MCT_FLOAT,
   MCT_INT
}

template<class T>
class MyBuffer
{
public:
   MyBuffer (int size, MyCallType type)
   : mData (new T[size]),
   mType (type)
   {}
   ~MyBuffer ()
   {
   delete mData;
   }
   MyCallType getType () { return mType; }

   T* getData(){ return mData; }
private:
   T *mData;
   MyCallType mType;
}


class Manager
{
public:
   Manager (){}
   /* a lot of code */
   void process ()
   {
       switch (mType)
       {
           case MyCallType::MCT_DOUBLE:
           customProcess <double>();
           break;

           case MyCallType::MCT_FLOAT:
           customProcess <float>();
           break;

           / *more cases*/
       }
   }

   template<typename T>
   void customProcess ()
   {
       MyBuffer<T> *myCast = reinterpret_cast <MyBuffer <T> *>(mBuffer);
       T *myData = myCast->getData ();
       /* a lot of process */
   }

private:
   void *mBuffer;
   MyCallType mType;
}
```

I want to avoid the switch case on "process ()" because I have a lot of function on the manager that work in the same way. Can anybody help me? That I want is possible?

Comment: Template arguments and runtime inputs cannot interact. Templates only exist during compilation and runtime inputs only exist during runtime.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're looking for [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: Thank you so much (n_n)
 I finally realized that I wanted to do is not possible due to the architecture and std::variant can't be used either (u_u).
Now I'm using a macro like this "#define runTemplate(func,type) if(type == MyCallType::MCT_FLOAT){ func<float>(); } else{ func<ushort>(); }" and "runTemplate(customProcess,mType)"

Comment: @EsmeraldaQuintero That is not a very good solution. Stay away from preprocessor macros when C++ features can do the same job. In this case, why not simply make `runTemplate()` be a templated function? `template<typename T> void runTemplate(funcType<T> func) { func(); }  ...  runTemplate<float>(customProcess);`  Or even abstract away the actual `func` type and let the compiler deduce it based on what kind of functions the caller actually passes in: `template<typename funcType> void runTemplate(funcType func) { func(); } ... runTemplate(customProcess<float>);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, that I wanted to avoid were the functions with the switch case.  Due to I have some template functions and the buffer could change on runtime, I create the wrapper function with the switch case for each template function and that increase my code a lot with repeated code where only the function to call changes. So I already tried to make a template function of a template function but I don't know if I made it right, because it still needed the function wrappers with the switch case.
Again, thank you for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As François said "Template arguments and runtime inputs cannot interact", so change the template's parameters during runtime is not possible, but a good solution could be the use of `std::variant` or `std::any` to avoid the switch cases, if you are using `C++17` (as Miles said).

The implementation that I actually use was the use of macros, due I wanted to reduce the code and I'm using `C++11`